# Conditional concatenation of string variables in tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to conditionally concatenate string variables using tidyverse.

Here is the toy data

```
df <- tibble(id = paste0("id_", 1:4),
             outcome = rep(x = c("simon",
                                 "garfunkel"),
                           times = 2),
             worth = rep(x = c("awesome",
                               "disposable"),
                         times = 2))

df

#   id    outcome   worth     
#   <chr> <chr>     <chr>     
# 1 id_1  simon     awesome   
# 2 id_2  garfunkel disposable
# 3 id_3  simon     awesome   
# 4 id_4  garfunkel disposable
```

I can use `unite()` from `tidyr` to combine the `id` column and 'worth' column like so

```
df %>%
  unite("id", c(id, worth))

#   id              outcome  
#   <chr>           <chr>    
# 1 id_1_awesome    simon    
# 2 id_2_disposable garfunkel
# 3 id_3_awesome    simon    
# 4 id_4_disposable garfunkel
```

But there are a few problems with this, some problems with the output and some problems with the way I generated it.

First, **I would like to retain the original column whereas `unite()` simply concatenates the two columns**. I tried `unite` within `mutate` but this generated an error.

Second, and most important, **rather than simply concatenating a column I would like to make the new cocantenated `id` column a combination of the `id` column and the `worth` column but *conditional on the*** `outcome` ***column*.** I tried to do this using `case_when()` within `mutate()` but got confused where to put the `paste0()` function and/or whether `unite()` could be used inside `case_when()`.

Third, and related to the second point, **I need to concatenate only a *part* of the `worth` column into the `id` column.** ideally using a regex substitution, capturing only the first *x* letters of the `worth` column

Basically I need the new dataset to look like the dataframe below, but using conditional and string-concantenation mechanics

```
tibble(id = paste0(paste0("id_", 1:4), 
                   rep(c("_awes", "_disp"))),
       outcome = rep(x = c("simon",
                           "garfunkel"),
                     times = 2),
       worth = rep(x = c("awesome",
                         "disposable"),
                   times = 2))

#   id          outcome   worth     
#   <chr>       <chr>     <chr>     
# 1 id_1_awes   simon     awesome   
# 2 id_2_disp   garfunkel disposable
# 3 id_3_awes   simon     awesome   
# 4 id_4_disp   garfunkel disposable
```

Any help much appreciated.

(p.s. apologies if you think Garfunkel was also awesome)

Comment: `tidyr::unite` keeps the original columns if you set `remove = FALSE`. You said you want to combine strings conditionally, but I don't see what the condition is exactly. As for where you can use `unite`, it's called on a data frame, which is why you weren't able to use it within `mutate` or `case_when`. It's a somewhat confusing function so I'd recommend studying its docs

Comment: Thanks for responding @camille. It would be combining `id` and `worth` conditional on `outcome`.  You could get it with `df %>% mutate(newid = case_when(outcome == "simon" ~ paste0(id, "_awes"), outcome == "garfunkel" ~ paste0(id, "_disp")))` but I was wondering if the same result was possible with a regex of some kind? (i.e. *extracting* part of the `worth` column rather than specifying it anew in the conditional statement)

Comment: In your example, simon is always paired with awesome and garfunkel is always paired with disposable, i.e. it's just `paste(id, substr(worth, 1, 4), sep = "_")`. There isn't actually a condition—you're just pasting pieces of the same row. Is that not going to be the case for your full project?

Comment: Yes I know, it's an unfortunate example. And no that will not be the case for my full project.

Comment: Your `substr()` solution within paste is what I was looking for. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% 
   mutate(worth1 = substr(worth, 1, 4)) %>%
   unite(id, id, worth1)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  id        outcome   worth     
  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     
1 id_1_awes simon     awesome   
2 id_2_disp garfunkel disposable
3 id_3_awes simon     awesome   
4 id_4_disp garfunkel disposable
```

Answer (score 0):

I put up a very confusing example, which, as @camille pointed out, had some redundancy in that the column I wanted to condition on followed an identical pattern to the column I wanted to extract, hence removing the need for conditioning at all. All I can say is mea culpa. However, since people have already provided solutions based on the original, confusing dataset I will leave the example as-is. Based on their answers the following is what I was looking for

```
df %>%
  mutate(newid = case_when(outcome == "simon" ~ paste(id, substr(worth, 1, 4), sep = "_"),
                           outcome == "garfunkel" ~ paste(id, substr(worth, 1, 4), sep = "_")))

#   id    outcome   worth      newid    
#   <chr> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>    
# 1 id_1  simon     awesome    id_1_awes
# 2 id_2  garfunkel disposable id_2_disp
# 3 id_3  simon     awesome    id_3_awes
# 4 id_4  garfunkel disposable id_4_disp
```

This solution conditions on the `outcome` variable but *extracts* the first four characters of the `worth` variable and combines that with the `id variable. Thanks to the responders for helping me with this.